# redux saga, issue wit Connect()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to fetch some data from my API using redux-saga. Unfortunately it's failing and I receive `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.fetchData is not a function`. Also `this.props.someInfo` is undefined. Since I'm making some console log I saw that function `getData` is not entered. I believe that it means that there is an issue with firing the action. Unfortunately I have no idea what might be wrong or how to fix it.

`createStore.js`

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import createSageMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';
import rootSaga from './rootSaga';
// import {rootSaga} from '../sagas/FAQSaga';

const sagaMiddleware = createSageMiddleware();

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const middleware = applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware);
    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        compose (
            middleware,
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() // for displaying in google dev tools
        )
    );

    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

    return store;
};
```

`rootSaga.js`

```
import { fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import FAQSaga from '../sagas/FAQSaga.js';

export default function * rootSaga() {
    yield [
        fork(FAQSaga)
    ];
}
```

`FAQSaga.js`

```
import * as actions from '../actions/FAQActions';
import axios from 'axios';
import { call, put, take, fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export function* getData() {
    try {
        console.log('getdata');
        const response = yield call(axios.get, 'http://localhost:8080/rest/book/all');
        const data = yield response.json();
        yield put(actions.GET_FAQ.SUCCESS(data));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('erorr');
        console.log(e);
        yield put(actions.GET_FAQ.FAILURE(e));
    }
}

export function* watchData() {
    console.log('watchData');
    while (true) {
        console.log('true');
        yield take(actions.GET_FAQ.REQUEST);
        yield fork(getData);
    }
    // yield takeEvery(actions.GET_FAQ.REQUEST, getData);
}

function * FAQSaga() {
    console.log('FAQSaga');
    yield [
        fork(watchData)
    ];
}

export default FAQSaga;
```

`FAQActions.js`

```
import {REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE, action} from './helpers';

const GET_FAQ_BASE = 'GET_FAQ_';
export const GET_FAQ = {
    REQUEST: GET_FAQ_BASE + REQUEST,
    SUCCESS: GET_FAQ_BASE + SUCCESS,
    FAILURE: GET_FAQ_BASE + FAILURE
};

const POST_FAQ_BASE = 'POST_FAQ_';
export const POST_FAQ = {
    REQUEST: POST_FAQ_BASE + REQUEST,
    SUCCESS: POST_FAQ_BASE + SUCCESS,
    FAILURE: POST_FAQ_BASE + FAILURE
};

export const getFAQ = {
    request: () => action(GET_FAQ.REQUEST),
    success: response => action(GET_FAQ.SUCCESS, {response}),
    failure: error => action(GET_FAQ.FAILURE, {error})
};

export const postFAQ = {
    request: data => action(POST_FAQ.REQUEST, {data}),
    success: response => action(POST_FAQ.SUCCESS, {response}),
    failure: error => action(POST_FAQ.FAILURE, {error})
};
```

`FAQContainer.js`

```
import React from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from '../../actions/FAQActions';

import FAQ from './FAQ';

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return ({
        fetchData: () => {dispatch(actions.getFAQ.request)}
    })
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return ({ someInfo: "some info" + state})
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FAQ);
```

`FAQ.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

// import { connect } from 'react-redux'
// import * as actions from '../../actions/FAQActions';


class FAQ extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('this.props.someInfo');
        console.log(this.props.someInfo);
        console.log('this.props.fetchData()');
        console.log(this.props.fetchData())
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Here some Frequently Asked Questions will be displayed.</p>
                {console.log('FAQ')}
                { this.props.children }
                <button type="button" onClick={this.postLoginData}>
                    post
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

FAQ.propTypes = {};

export default FAQ;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using `FAQContainer` and not `FAQ` in some parent component?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code in FAQContainer.js

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        fetchData() {
            dispatch(actions.getFAQ.request);
        }
    };
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return (state) => ({
        someInfo: "some info" + state;
    });
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help. Do you maybe have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a function in props you could simply map the `dispatch` to your props and dispatch any action you need directly from your component:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch
  };
}
```

And in your component now you could simply do:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(actions.getFAQ.request);
}
```

And since dispatch just is for triggering an action and starting the redux data flow I am not sure why you are calling `console.log` on the output of your dispatch call. You can not get the result of your asynchronous API call in a synchronous way, it should be mapped using `mapStateToProps` when connecting your component to redux.

The other solution which I think is going to be helpful is to use `bindActionCreators` from redux:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../actions/youractions';

//...

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch),
    dispatch,
  };
}
```

which maps the actions into your props. Using this solution you won't need the `dispatch` your actions manually they would be all automatically mapped to your props.